# Eslint - How to lint a given large list of files

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

The doc states I can pass an explicit list of files to Eslint using the [CLI](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface) (eg. `eslint file1.js file2.js`) but my list contains hundreds of files. So my questions are:

- Is it feasible/best practice to pass hundreds of files via the CLI?
- If not, how to tell Eslint to lint only a specific list of files?

For the second option, here is what I've tried:

- I used the [overrides](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface) option but I still have to lint all the files of my project.
- I ignored all files in `.eslintignore` and made exceptions for the files included in my list but Eslint throws an error saying I've ignored all the files.